# If-else inside Vue Tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am creating my first Vue-app and I want to render things using something like if-else

So consider this incorrect a tag

```
<a :href="status === true ? '#' : 'url'">
```

Here what I want is if the status is true than href should not do anything on click and if it isn't true then it should have url provided.

My Export Default looks like this

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "socialBoxes",
  props: ["status", "url", "name"]
};
</script>
```

Any idea/how about what is wrong with my syntax/how could I achieve desired results?

**[Update:]** When condition isn't true, instead of loading url passed as props, it appends "url" to url.

I am passing my url like this

```
<SocialBoxes
          :url="eventbrite_auth_url"
```

Comment: Re: your update, if `url` is a variable, remove the single quotes around it.

Comment: 'When condition isn't true, instead of loading url passed as props, it appends "url" to url.'  - to url as variable or to url as href attribute? Can you be more specific please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.You have added extra single quote i guess. `<a :href="status === true ? '#' : url">`

Comment: @anny123 That's a *separate* quoting issue, I suspect. If `url` is a variable/property, it shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the status on click with Event object:

```
<a :href="url" @click="checkStatus"></a>

methods: {
  checkStatus(e) {
    if (status === false) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For conditional rendering, use `v-if` rather than `v-bind:href`

```
<a :href="url" v-if="status === false">sometext</a>
<a href="#" v-else>sometext</a>
```